# Joint Cummulative Distribution Identity

Tags: probability

I understand how to prove the following using Venn diagrams (asked and answered [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278722/joint-distribution-function)) but would also like to be able to show it using the general properties of distributions. The following comes from chapter 6 of Ross's First Course In Probability.

Let $P\{X\leq a \, \wedge Y\leq b\} = F(a,b)$ be the probability that the $X\leq a$ and $Y\leq b$. Prove the following claim:

$P\{a_1 \lt X \leq a_2 \,\, \wedge \,\, b_1 \lt Y \leq b_2 \} = F(a_2,b_2) + F(a_1,b_1) - F(a_1,b_2) - F(a_2,b_1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to show this is to express $A\cup B$ as the equivalent union of disjoint sets $A \cup A^c B$.

We will use the following notation:

$$P(X\leq a) = F_X (a)$$

$$P(Y\leq b) = F_Y (b)$$

$$P(X\leq a \cap Y \leq b) = F(a,b)$$

We will also use the following identity in the below solution:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P\{X > a \cap Y > b\} &=& 1 - P\{ X \leq a \cup Y \leq b\} \\
&=& 1 - P\{X \leq a\} - P\{Y \leq b\} + P\{ X \leq a \cap Y \leq b\} \\
&=& 1 - F_X (a) - F_Y (b) + F(a,b)
\end{array}
$$

We rewrite the original problem as

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P(a_1 < X \cap X \leq a_2 \cap b_1 < Y \cap Y \leq b_2) &=& 1 - P(X\leq a_1 \cup X>a_2 \cup Y \leq b_1 \cup Y > b_2 ) \\
&=& 1 -P[ ( X\leq a_1 \cup Y \leq b_1) \cup ( X>a_2 \cup Y > b_2 ) ]
\end{array}
$$

Using $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(A^cB)$ and $P(A\cup B)=P(A) + P(B) - P(AB)$, we have

$$
\\
1 - \left[ \left(F_X (a_1) + F_Y (b_1) - F(a_1,b_1) \right) + \left( P( (X > a_1 \cap Y > b_1 ) \cap (X > a_2 \cup Y > b_2 ) ) \right) \right]
\\
$$

Since $\{X > a_1\} \supset \{X > a_2\}$ and $\{Y>b_1\} \supset \{Y>b_2\}$, the last term in the above equation is equal to

$$
\\
\begin{array}{rcl}
P( (X>a_2 \cap Y>b_1) \cup (X>a_1 \cap Y>b_2) ) &=& P(X>a2 \cap Y>b1) + P(X>a_1 \cap Y > b_2)\\
&&  - P(X>a_2 \cap Y > b_2)
\end{array}
$$

Using the above identity for $P(X>a \cap Y>b)$ and combining terms yields:

$$
P(a_1 < X \leq a_2 \cap b_1 < Y \leq b_2 ) = F(a_1,b_1)+F(a_2,b_2) - F(a_1,b_2) - F(a_2,b_1)
$$